# Access variable from html in JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tabs

I have an `md-tab`, and what I want to do is to access the selected label in the controller, but I try to do this I get an undefined error. Does anybody have any idea why ??

This is my html:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="selectedTab">
<md-tab ng-repeat="data in Data" label="{{data.month}}">
<md-content class="md-padding" >
<div class="table-responsive">
    ...
</div>
...
```

And in my controller I want to assign `data.month` like this:

```
$scope.var = data.month;
```

Comment: use `$scope` i.e `$scope.data.month`

Comment: @blaa did it work?

Comment: I wrote it like this: $scope.somevariable = $scope.data.month;
      console.log($scope.somevariable);. But I get this error: angular.js:13236 TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined

Comment: try this if it get printed $scope.somevariable = $scope.data; and tell what is the value

Comment: this is what it gets printed undefined

Comment: have you defined data anywhere?

Comment: no, I have not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123674/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-blaa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing $scope , also change var to someother variable since its a keyword

```
   $scope.somevariable = $scope.data.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html you are iterating 'Data' variable which is suppose to be array of object which contains the 'month' property and provided to view by your controller.
But here I can see any 'Data' variable coming from controller. Your code in controller should look like

```js
$scope.Data = [{month:jan},{month:feb},{month:oct},{month:dec}]
```

or Similar to this.